# When using a custom UITableViewCell the imageview frame is zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I created a custom UITableViewCell , but want to use the standard UIImageView that is in the cell.

I notice that the frame is always zeroed , which is causing me problems

```
@implementation MyCustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    // the style is "default" style
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
// I need to override the cells image 
    if (self) {
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImageToUseInThisCell"]; // The image view frame is {0,0,0,0}
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: put a breakpoint in `-initWithStyle:`. does it hit this method? also, kindly include your `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (just for clarity). Even if it does hit `-initWithStyle:`, it won't return any frame sizes because the cell hasn't loaded yet which means the `subview`s haven't been created yet (_i.e. are `nil`_). You would be better off with frame specific related stuff in `-layoutSubviews` and as for setting the image property, I would do it in `-awakeFromNib`

Comment: btw... I am not totally sure about the specifics of your question so I'm just putting this out there (_although you look like you should be knowing_) but you have to manually drag a `UIImageView` object onto your custom `UITableViewCell`. There is no standard `UIImageView` in a custom UITableViewCell

Answer (score 1):

You won't get any frame sizes in the `-initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` because the cell hasn't loaded yet which means the `subview`s haven't been created yet (*i.e. are `nil`*) and hence a 0 frame size.
<sub>Even for a `viewController`, you won't get frame size in the `-initWithNibName:` method.</sub>

You would be better off with:

1. Frame specific related stuff in `-layoutSubviews`
2. Setting an initial property in `-awakeFromNib` (*or directly via IB*)

Anyways, try this:

```
//does this method even run? it shouldn't for a custom UITableViewCell
//unless you've mixed up things unnecessarily
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"initWithStyle -- %@",self.myImageView);
    }
    return self;
}

//do frame related stuff here
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    //fyi: this method is called anytime any frame changes

    NSLog(@"layoutSubviews -- %@",self.myImageView);
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    //fyi: this method is called when the view is pulled from the IB

    // Initialization code
    NSLog(@"awakeFromNib -- %@",self.myImageView);

    //do you thang here
    [self.myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImageToUseInThisCell"]];
}
```

---

- [`-layoutSubviews` on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/728372/2857130)
- [`-awakeFromNib` on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9122344/2857130)

Comment: It was zero sized there as well

Comment: @AvnerBarr : have you dragged and connected the `UIImageView` object via the IB? (_in my example, it's called `myImageView`_)

Comment: @AvnerBarr. then xib? add the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to your question for clarity

Comment: Seems that the problem is when dequing with reuse identifier and cell identifier a custom cell the cell won't set those properties

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the problem is when dequeuing a custom cell with a reuse identifier and index path the custom cell base class doesn't set those properties. This is not mentioned in the docs which is very unfortunate.

Comment: I suspect so as well.