# When in the view's flow are the run time attributes actually set?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, runtime

Can anyone please tell me when are the run time attributes that we set in the storyboard actually sets their values to their respective properties of the object?

I am sure they are set after `initWithCoder:` and its set using

`setValue:(id)value forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath`

and before `awakeFromNib`

These run time attributes that you get from the nib, must be unarchived I feel and then probably maintained in memory for sometime?

Any details will be good :) or any topic I should refer to

Answer (score 0):

They are initialized right before they are sent an awakeFromNib message.

Post with more information: [When does awakeFromNib get called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122344/when-does-awakefromnib-get-called)

Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib