# UICollectionViewCell animation stops when segued to a new UIViewController and back

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` within a `UICollectionView` that animates correctly when the collection view is initially displayed. However when I segue into a new `UIViewController` and back to the original one, the animation stop.

```
class EmptyDishesCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var plateImage: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var knifeImage: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var forkImage: UIImageView!

  @IBOutlet weak var emptyBackgroundView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var plateHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
  @IBOutlet weak var plateWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setupBorders()
    setupImages()
    beginAnimation()
    setShadow()
  }

  func setupBorders() {
    self.emptyBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
    self.emptyBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
  }

  func setupImages() {
    self.plateImage.tintColor = UIColor.projectBackgroundSuperLightGray
    self.forkImage.tintColor = UIColor.projectBackgroundSuperLightGray
    self.knifeImage.tintColor = UIColor.projectBackgroundSuperLightGray
  }

  func beginAnimation() {
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 2.4, delay: 0.0, options: [.calculationModeLinear, .repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
      UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 2/5, animations: {
        let moveLeft = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -5.0, y: 0.0)
        let moveRight = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 5.0, y: 0.0)
        let rotate = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 5.0)
        self.forkImage.transform = moveLeft
        self.knifeImage.transform = moveRight
        self.plateImage.transform = rotate
      })
      UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1/3, relativeDuration: 1/5, animations: {
//        let wait = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -5.0, y: 0.0)
//        self.forkImage.transform = wait
      })
      UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 2/3, relativeDuration: 2/5, animations: {
        self.forkImage.transform = .identity
        self.knifeImage.transform = .identity
        self.plateImage.transform = .identity
      })
    })
  }
}
```

I'm assuming when a view is transitioned out of sight, the animation automatically stops, however when it's put back into view it needs to be kicked off again manually.

so naturally I thought putting the animation block into `didMoveToWindow` would fix it, but it was a no go.

Any help would be appreciated

[image].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `collectionView.reloadData()` in your `viewWillAppear(animated)`? I'm guessing that won't help unless you call your `beginAnimation()` in your `cellForItemAt`.

So you're calling `beginAnimation()` inside your `awakeFromNib()`,

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9122393/3231194

> awakeFromNib gets called after the view and its subviews were
>   allocated and initialized. It is guaranteed that the view will have
>   all its outlet instance variables set.

I'm proposing you just call your `EmptyDishesCollectionViewCell`'s `beginAnimation()` function during `cellForItemAt`. And if necessary, just reload your `collectionView`. Hope it helps!.

Comment: Calling `collectionView.reloadData()` in `viewWillAppear(animated)` triggered the `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` and adding `cell.beginAnimation()` in the `cellForItemAt` fixed it. It seems a bit heavy handed to reloaded the whole collection but it works. Thank you