# Can't access to variable in my cell content

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, cell

I'm looking to get my variable content in my awakeFromNib function in my custom cell.

Actually, I pass my data like this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "question_cell", for: indexPath) as! QuestionsCell

    cell.answers = ["Answer 1", "Answer 2"]

    return cell
}
```

In my QuestionCell file, I've got my variable declared like this :
`var answers = [String]()`

And When I want to print my answer variable, I've got an empty array in the output console `[]`

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    print("HELLOOOOOOOOOOOO !!!!!!!!!!!!")
    print(answers)
}
```

Could you please help me to solve this ?
Thank you

Comment: `cellForRowAt` is called when the cell is to be drawn. `awakeFromNib` is called when the viewController is decoded from the storyboard. `awakeFromNib` happens first. It doesn't happen again. So answers at the point is going to be `nil`. You real question is **when is `awakeFromNib` called?** I've linked a similar question for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does awakeFromNib get called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122344/when-does-awakefromnib-get-called)

Answer (score 2):

`awakeFromNib()` Would be called before the line `cell.answers = ["Answer 1", "Answer 2"]` in `cellForRowAt` is called.

To respond to changes to answers, you can do the property observer `didSet` to your variable definition.

Just change `var answers = [String]()` to:

```
var answers = [String]() {
    didSet {
        print(answers)
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, `awakeFromNib` is only called when the cell is created, not when it is reused, so even if the property was set before that function it would only be called once

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already did it but I forgot to make a ReloadData for my tableView so The content wasn't loaded. Thanks for your help 